# Crud operation using Ajax not working in Laravel 7.3 version

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying create an ajax crud in Laravel, I have used yazra datatable here, which is working fine and fetching data nicely. But when trying to insert a data, it does nothing (though there is no error). [image]

my codes for they form is (some form elements are removed in order to comply with stackoverflow's "mostly code" issue  ) :

```
<form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right"  action="" method="post" 
    id="addBootcamp" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="m-portlet__body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="form-group  m-form__group {{ $errors->has('course_type') ? 
                  'has-danger' : '' }}">
                        <label class="form-control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> 
                       Course Type </label>
                        <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" 
                         name="course_id" id="course_type">
                            <option value="">---- Select ----</option>
                            <option value="1">Cyber Security Awareness</option>
                            <option value="0">Others</option>
                        </select>
                        @if ($errors->has('course_type'))
                            <div class="form-control-feedback">{{ $errors- 
                        >first('course_type') }}</div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="form-group  m-form__group {{ $errors->has('end_date') ? 'has- 
                       danger' : '' }}">
                        <label class="form-control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> 
                       {{__('course.end_date')}} </label>
                        <input id="end_date" type="text" class="form-control m-input 
                       m_datepicker_1 clear" name="end_date" value="{{ old('end_date') }}" 
                       placeholder="{{__('course.end_date')}}" autocomplete="off"/>
                        @if ($errors->has('end_date'))
                            <div class="form-control-feedback">{{ $errors->first('end_date') 
                        }}</div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

             
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="form-group  m-form__group">
                        <label class="form-control-label"> {{__('bootcamp.bootcamp_image')}} 
                      </label>
                        <input id="bootcamp_image" type="file" class="form-control-file clear" 
                     name="bootcamp_image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-portlet__foot m-portlet__foot--fit">
            <div class="m-form__actions text-center">
                <a href="{{ route('course.index') }}" class="btn btn-outline-brand"><i 
            class="fa fa-times"></i> {{__('common.cancel')}}</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> 
            {{__('common.save')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Codes for ajax Functionality are :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function clearData(){
    $('.clear').val('');
}

//-------------------------------------------Add a Bootcamp----------------------------------- 
  --------

$('#addBootcamp').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let course_id = $('#course_type').val();
    let bootcamp_event_title = $('#bootcamp_event_title').val();
    let location = $('#location').val();
    let event_start = $('#event_start').val();
    let event_end = $('#event_end').val();
    let availability = $('#availability').val();
    let status = $('#status').val();
    console.log(course_id);
    $.ajax({
        url : '../../admin/add-bootcamp',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            course_id : course_id,
            bootcamp_event_title : bootcamp_event_title,
            location : location,
            event_start : event_start,
            event_end : event_end,
            availability : availability,
            status : status,
        },
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
            clearData();
        },
    })
});

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
   });
});
```

Routes are :

```
Route::get('admin/bootcamp/get-data', 'AdminBootcamp@getData');
Route::get('admin/bootcamp/create', 'AdminBootcamp@getData');
Route::resource('admin/bootcamp','AdminBootcamp');
Route::get('admin/bootcamp','AdminBootcamp@index');
Route::post('admin/add-bootcamp','AdminBootcamp@store');
```

Codes from my method :

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()) {
        AdminBootcamp::create([
            'course_id' => $request->course_id,
            'bootcamp_event_title' => $request->bootcamp_event_title,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'event_start' => $request->start_date,
            'event_end' => $request->end_date,
            'availability' => $request->availability,
            'status' => $request->status_id,
            'bootcamp_image' => $request->bootcamp_image,
        ]);

        $msg = 'success !';

        echo json_encode($msg);
    }

}
```

Model :

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Model\admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class AdminBootcamp extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'bootcamps';
    protected $fillable =

    ['course_id','bootcamp_event_title','location','event_start',
   'event_end','availability','status'];
 }
```

Comment: post your routes

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya Please check at the bottom of the post

Comment: change url in ajax to  url : '{{url("admin/add-bootcamp")}}',

Comment: then change your url '{{url("admin/add-bootcamp")}} or direct "/admin/add-bootcamp"

Comment: hey @JohnLobo , thanks for coming again :) it's giving an error after changing the URL now : 
vendors.bundle.js:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/bootcamp/%7B%7Burl(%22admin/add-bootcamp%22)%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya Please check the reply at john Lobo

Comment: url : '/admin/add-bootcamp', use direct

Comment: @azim can you method code as well

Comment: @JohnLobo , I have shared the method code at the bottom of my post

Comment: @azim share model as well AdminBootcamp

Comment: @JohnLobo added :)

Comment: @azim.code looks but you are saying data not inserted into db .so better check dd($request->all()) so you can verify whether data getting from ajax.even you can check in network tab

Comment: @JohnLobo the post url returns 419 status , I also have used resource method, is it causing the problem ?

Comment: call $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
   }); before the ajax call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234219/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-azim).